# Google Maps API v3 marker with image and a text on top of this image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to display an image on a marker but on this image I'd like to also place some text (that I need to change dynamically during the life cycle of my application).

I've tried [markerwithlabel](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerwithlabel) and they have two different examples, one with a [picture](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerwithlabel/examples/picturelabel.html) and another with [text](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markerwithlabel/examples/basic.html) but I'd like to combine the two to create something similar to this:

[image]

Where "Wheeee!" should be specified (and be updatable) as text.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How about using SVG as the icon?

Comment: @chiu Hmm I suppose that might work. Would that be easier?

Comment: Hi, I suppose you can probably find an SVG library which fits your needs, but I'm no familiar with them. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have php, with GD library?

Comment: No I'm using clojurescript and clojure on the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) from [Google Maps Api Libraries](http://googlemaps.github.io/libraries.html). You can add any HTML to your marker (as showin in the example [here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/examples/richmarker.html)).

So in your case, using `RichMarker.setContent()` (Api reference [here](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/reference.html)) you would add custom HTML, something like (roughly, from your provided picture example):

```
myMarker.setContent('<div class="callout_bubble">
                       <i class="some_icon"></i>
                       <span class="inside_text" id="my_marker_X_text">Wheee!</span>
                     </div>');
```

And then add css styles to style it any way you want. Also you can change text inside `<span>` with id `my_marker_X_text` using js. If you want multiple markers just assign them multiple unique ids, or always change whole content of marker, that's up to you.