# How to show marker with the city name - Google Geochart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

How can I show a name with a marker, currently there is only 1 option to select between "markers" or "text". If I choose the "text" then there is no click option on text click. Is it possible to have both on a map? If not then can we have the click event on a text?

```
var dataCities = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['City', ''],
            ['Lahore', 1],
            ['Karachi', 1],
            ['Islamabad', 1],
            ["Gilgit", 1]
        ]);

        var options = {
            region: 'PK',
            displayMode: 'text',
            width: 834,
            height: 521,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            datalessRegionColor: '#9bd5e1',
            defaultColor: '#fff',
            legend: 'none',
            showTooltip: true,
            showInfoWindow: true,
            sizeAxis: {
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue: 5
            },

            colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#739FA8', '#739FA8', '#739FA8', '#739FA8', '#739FA8']
            }

        };

function myClickHandler() {
            var city = '';
            var selection = chart.getSelection();
            if (selection.length > 0) {
                city = dataCities.og[selection[0].row].c[0].v;
                //alert(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
                document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = '';
                document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = countryCity + ' , ' + city;
            }
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', myClickHandler);
        chart.draw(dataCities, options);
```

Here is the fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svtykw9o/)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145271/markers-with-text-on-a-google-geochart

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the geochart to have provinces in the Geochart.

```
    var options = {
      region: 'IT',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      displayMode: 'text',
      colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']},
      sizeAxis: {minSize: 12, maxSize:20},
      enableRegionInteractivity: true   
    };
```

Then you can just add the `regionClick` event handler to send it through to your `myClickHandler()` method.

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', myClickHandler); 
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

Here's an updated version of your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/svtykw9o/2/) with my modifications to your code.

Comment: what would I do If I am working on a cities level then?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't go that far, the limit is provinces. Maybe you could make a custom info window on your clickhandler function.